# Redirect running process STDOUT/STDERR to SSH STDOUT using GDB

Tags: linux, redirect, gdb, embedded, stdout

I have a process running on an embedded system (linux).
its STDOUT/STDERR is the console which is on a serial port.

I would like to redirect its ouputs (standard and error) to that of an SSH session.
I have read you can do similar operations with GDB, but I don't know how you would redirect to the SSH session's STDOUT/STDERR instead of to a file.

I can't do it to a file because of low disk resources. Also I have seen some examples using a named pipe, but I don't have mkfifo command available. I do have GDB.

Also, assuming this is possible, would the process terminate when I close the SSH session? If so, could I redirect back before I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as long as you can call libc functions from gdb.

```
#ssh root@embedded
```

Query daemon output location:

```
# ls -l /proc/`pidof daemon`/fd/1
/proc/13202/fd/1 -> /dev/null
```

It can be not null, it can point to some other console or even some pipe or file, store this location somewhere. Query your ssh session output location:

```
# ls /proc/self/fd/1 -l
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 дек.  15 16:51 /proc/self/fd/1 -> /dev/pts/9
```

or simply call `tty` if you have it.

Now goes the work:

```
# gdb -p `pidof daemon`
..
81      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) call open("/dev/pts/9",2,0)
$1 = 0x3
(gdb) call dup2(3,2)
$2 = 0x2
(gdb) call dup2(3,1)
$3 = 0x1
(gdb) quit
Detaching from program: /root/daemon, process 13202
 daemon output/errorput
```

Repeat the same steps before exit from ssh session, just replace `/dev/pts/9` with initial output location in the `open` syscall.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, and it gives me a better understanding on how this works. You may want to add a "-l" to the first ls, it didn't let me do it.